# Flutter: How to set different colors for DropdownItems and for DropdownButton selected item?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have included `DropdownButton` in my project but I stucked with these problem.

I have tried to use Theme on it but it also changes the both of colors. I can still change the background color of dropdown but I wanted it to be white with black text.

Here you can see the [screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXYGb.jpg), the dropdown is white because text color is also white

```
AccentColorOverride(
  child: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
        hintColor: Colors.white,
        selectedRowColor: Colors.white),
    child: DropdownButton<String>(
      value: selectedRegion,
      hint: Text(hint_label_region, style: white18),
      isExpanded: true,
      underline: Container(
        height: 1.0,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Color(0xFFBDBDBD),
                    width: 2))),
      ),
      items: <String>[
        'A',
        'B',
        'C',
        'D'
      ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: new Text(
            value,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
          selectedRegion = newValue;
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If anyone still needs, by [Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/selectedItemBuilder.html) you can set a custom selectedItemBuilder, which means you can basically display anything you want respecting the List type. Here's an example:

```
var listSorted = list.map((dropdownItem) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>(
        child: Text("${dropdownItem.label}",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        value: dropdownItem.value);
    }).toList();
return Container(
      child: DropdownButton(
        isExpanded: true,
        iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,
        underline: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 1,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        value: valueToUpdate,
        items: listSorted,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt) {
          return list.map<Widget>((item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text("${item.label}",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                value: item.value);
          }).toList();
        },
        dropdownColor: backgroundColor,
      )));
```

Comment: I would expect a type for selectedItemBuilder: Function(Widget) but not Function(List<Widget>). Maybe I missed the point... Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Leo mentioned before you should use selectedItemBuilder and pass the new created list , you can create a function that create the two lists and takes whatever you want to change ..
code will be like that:

```
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _createChildrenList(Color textColor) =>typesOfPayments
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: CustomText(
        color: textColor,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        text: value,
        fontFamily: HelperCubit.getFontFamilyByLanguage(context),
      ),
    );   }).toList();
```

on drop down button use the created function

```
items: _createChildrenList(Colors.white),
selectedItemBuilder: (context) =>_createChildrenList(MaterialData.kPrimaryColor),
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work, define a state like '_selectedItemValue', call setState when user taps on an item, and render your DropDownMenuItem based on this state.

```
    .
    .
    .
    ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                 setState() {
                   _selectedItemValue = value;
                 }
              } ,
              child:DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Container(
                  color: value == _selectedItemValue ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
                  child: new Text(
                    value,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),),
            ),);
          }).toList(),
```

Comment: I've checked your code sample and it seems that I wont work due to several reason. Firstly your mapping the wrong widget, secondly the onTap of the Gesturedetector will be overwritten by the onTap Function of its child which is in this case the DropdownMenuItem.